# How to locate style in Less file

Tags: visual-studio, dictionary, less, web-essentials

I have noticed that web essentials for visual studio creates a .css.map file when compiling less. Does this mean it is possible to navigate from a selector in the css file back to the selector in the associated less file? If so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VS 2013, if you enable LESS preview window, you can leverage `Go To Definition` command on a selector in preview to highlight the corresponding selector in LESS source. (via right-click context menu or press F12 in preview window -- see [#809](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/pull/809)). When applicable, it will also load the `@import`ed document, where the source is available.

On that note, there are [*precession issues*](https://github.com/hcatlin/libsass/issues/324) with libsass' source-map. For that matter, it doesn't work well in SCSS editor.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the idea of source maps is to map code or css from a compressed file back to the original uncompressed version.

Here is a good guide to using source maps in Chrome and Firefox.

[An introduction to source maps](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/introduction-source-maps)